# java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 70 Exception Details

Tags: java, openjpa

getting

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 70
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/mb/mf/tr/fm/da/db/<entityclass>.<clinit>()V @61: ifnull
  Reason:
    Expected stackmap frame at this location.
```

i used -noverify and -XX:-UseSplitVerifier in jvm options. i am using jdk 1.7 using openjpa 1.x. i can't migrate to any newer or older version of jdk.

Comment: Please give little more explanation about your problem, when you are getting this exception

Answer (score 0):

Usually this error we will get when a jdk not installed properly, plz try to reinstall the jdk and try again.